# How to assign a binary value to rows based on the specific value in another column and a specified proportion in Python Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to simulate a population with different proportion of ethnic groups (i.e., English (en), and non-English (non-en)). In the example below, it is set out that the population is 50:50 English and non-English. Then I want to simulate a specific disease prevalence for each group. For example, I want to simulate there is 10% of people in the English group will have a disease (`Disease`), while 30% of the non-English group will have the same disease.

```
ETHNICITY
   non-en
       en
   non-en
   non-en
       en
   non-en
       en
       en
       en
   non-en
```

Code:

```
def create_test_df(prop_dict, n=10, seed=4):
    label_list = []
    prop_list = []
    for key, prop in prop_dict.items():
        label_list.append(key)
        prop_list.append(prop)
    np.random.seed(seed)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(n).reshape(n, 1)).applymap(
        lambda x: np.random.choice(label_list, p=prop_list))
    df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'ETHNICITY'}, inplace=True)
    return df

def simulate_disease_prop(df, varname, prop_dict):
    for key, prop in prop_dict.items():
        if df[varname] == key:
            return np.random.choice(['Disease', 'NonDisease'], p=[prop, 1-prop])

expected_popn_proportion = {
    'en': 0.5,
    'non-en': 0.5
    }

expected_disease_proportion = {
    'en': 0.1,
    'non-en': 0.3
    }

df_test = create_test_df(expected_popn_proportion)
df_test['SIM_DIS_STATUS'] = df_test.apply(simulate_disease_prop, 
    df_test, 'ETHNICITY', expected_disease_proportion)
```

Everything works except the last line (`TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`).

[Edit] Expected output:

```
ETHNICITY    SIM_DIS_STATUS
   non-en    Disease
       en    Disease
   non-en    NonDisease
   non-en    NonDisease
       en    NonDisease
   non-en    Disease
       en    NonDisease
       en    NonDisease
       en    NonDisease
   non-en    NonDisease
```

Comment: please show your expected output

Comment: Added to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. I am sure there is a more elegant solution.

```
def simulate_disease_prop(df, varname, prop_dict):
    counter = 1
    for key, prop in prop_dict.items():
        df['NEW_V{}'.format(str(counter))] = np.where(df[varname]==key, 
            np.random.choice(['Disease', 'NonDisease'], p=[prop, 1-prop], size=len(df)), np.nan)
            counter += 1

    new_cols = [x for x in df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('NEW_V')]]
    df['TEMP'] = df[new_cols].stack().groupby(level=0).agg(min)
    for i in new_cols:
        del df[i]
    return df['TEMP']

expected_disease_proportion = {
    'en': 0.30,
    'non-en': 0.10
    }

df_test['SIM_DIS_STATUS'] = simulate_disease_prop(df_test, 'ETHNICITY', expected_disease_proportion)
df_test['SIM_DIS_STATUS_V2'] = simulate_disease_prop(df_test, 'ETHNICITY', expected_disease_proportion)

print(df_test)
```

Output:

```
  ETHNICITY        TEMP SIM_DIS_STATUS SIM_DIS_STATUS_V2
0    non-en  NonDisease        Disease        NonDisease
1        en     Disease     NonDisease           Disease
2    non-en     Disease     NonDisease           Disease
3    non-en  NonDisease        Disease        NonDisease
4        en  NonDisease        Disease        NonDisease
5    non-en  NonDisease     NonDisease        NonDisease
6        en  NonDisease     NonDisease        NonDisease
7        en  NonDisease     NonDisease        NonDisease
8        en  NonDisease     NonDisease        NonDisease
9    non-en     Disease     NonDisease           Disease
```